# Использование разных времен ("привел" и "побеждает") в одном предложении

Tags: грамматика

Этот гол привел в бешеный восторг болельщиков стадиона, и команда побеждает в дерби со счетом 3:2!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет согласования в грамматическом понимании этого термина. Есть две фразы, соединенные в сложносочиненное предложение, у этих фраз разное грамматическое время.

Вопрос, насколько такое правильно, уместно ставить только с точки зрения стилистики. А это во многом вещь субъективная.

Чтобы ответить наверняка, надо знать контекст. Если победа команды уже состоялась, то использование настоящего времени вместо совершенного вида прошедшего не совсем удачно в этой фразе.

Ну а если это "побеждает" означает лишь текущую ситуацию, т. е. "ведет в счете", то почему нет? Вполне уместно.

Comment: Речь идет о состоявшейся победе, матч был в прошлом году. Спасибо, вашу мысль поняла.

Answer (score 0):

> > Есть две фразы, соединенные в сложносочиненное предложение

Механически соединенные, добавил бы я. Фраза, конечно, не смотрится.